# How to count the number of times a character symbol appears in a text file?

Tags: c, symbols

I am trying to write a program that reads in a text file and then counts the number of times a symbol (user's choice from the command line argument) appears throughout the text file. It then writes the number of times it appears to an output text file. My problem is that it doesn't successfully print symbols or numbers, whereas if I count the number of times a LETTER appears it works fine.

For example, if `input.txt` contains:

```
Hello my name is programmer!!
```

Then running:

```
$ gcc myProgram.c
$ ./a.out input.txt output.txt !
```

*Note* First argument: input.txt , Second argument: output.txt , Third argument: !

This should print:

```
$ cat output.txt
The character being written was '!' and it occurred 2 times.
$
```

However, it prints nothing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *finp;
    FILE *output;
    char letter;

    int ex=0;

    if((finp=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){

        printf("Error Reading input!\n");

    }

    while((letter = fgetc(finp))!=EOF){

        /*From ASCII TABLE*/
        if(letter==33){
            ex++;}}

    if(output=fopen(argv[2], "w")){


        if(strcmp(argv[3],"!")==0){
            fprintf(output, "The character being written was '%s' and it occured %d
                    times", argv[3], ex);
        }


        if(output==NULL){
            printf("ERROR\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    }
    fclose(finp);
}
```

Comment: The logic of your program is strange: You count all exclamation marks (on a guess) and later confirm that the char to count was "!"? Shouldn't you find out which character to count _before_ counting?

Comment: Also: use `int letter`, because that's the result of `fgetc`; exit when the input file can't be opened; Check whether ´output` is null _before_  you access it. And please indent your code.

Comment: Most shell programs attach special meaning to symbols. To avoid problems, enclose the symbol in quotes, e.g. `./a.out input.txt output.txt "!"`. Also check that `argc == 4` before using any of the arguments.

Comment: Dang, None of these suggestions have fixed my problem. 
(strcmp(argv[3],"!")
^^is this the correct syntax for symbols?

Comment: @RaoulDuke: Can you compile and run this code in that directory? Please use the same arguments that you are having problems with. https://gist.github.com/sharth/e951ba0b4e3d0d571323

Comment: the first thing the program should do is check argc to assure the value is 4.  if the value is not 4 then it should print a usage statement and exit

Comment: after every call to fopen, the resulting value should be checked (!=NULL) to assure the fopen was successful

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  the compiler emits a number of warnings and several errors.  Please post the actual code

Comment: the code, when the fopen for the input file fails, the code outputs an error message, then keeps right on executing rather than exiting.

Comment: EOF is an int, not a char, and fgetc() returns an int.  so the line 'char letter' should be 'int letter'

Comment: the code is making the assumption the third input parameter is '!' rather than actually accessing argv[3] to get the user selected character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several errors and some warnings raised by the compiler for the posted code.

Here is a version with the errors/warnings corrected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *finp   = NULL;
    FILE *output = NULL;
    int   letter; // character to be found

    int ex=0; // character occurrence counter

    if( 4 != argc )
    { // then wrong number of parameters.
        printf( "usage: %s <inFileName> <outFileName> <searchChar>", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, right number of parameters

    if( NULL == (finp=fopen(argv[1], "r") ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen for the input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( NULL == (output=fopen(argv[2], "w") ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen for the output file failed" );
        fclose( finp ); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( EOF != (letter = fgetc(finp) ) )
    {
        /*From ASCII TABLE*/
        if( letter == argv[3][0] )
        { // then desired character found
            ex++;
        } // end if
    } // end while

    fprintf(
        output,
        "The search character is '%c' and it occurred %d times\n",
        argv[3][0],
        ex);

    fclose(finp);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: I'm unconvinced that the `// end if` and `// end while` and related comments are helpful, and the `From ASCII TABLE` comment is no longer relevant.  Otherwise, though, you've fixed the issues in much the same way as I would/did.  Well done.

Comment: Say for example you decided to type:

./a.out input.txt output.txt ?


Why would the output be:


"The search character is '1' and it occurred 0 times


If your input file did contain a question mark also.

Comment: @RaoulDuke: You have a file `1` in your directory, so the shell expanded the `?` into `1`.  That's why [user3386109](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580863/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-character-symbol-appears-in-a-text-file/29582025#comment47310247_29580863) that you should quote the punctuation characters: `./a.out input.txt output.txt '?'` to ensure the shell doesn't treat them as metacharacters.  Use single quotes because backquotes still have meaning within double quotes. Use `"'"` for an actual single quote.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous little changes required, most of them identified in the comments.  Here's the code fixed more or less the way I'd do it.

#### Source code: `lc.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *finp;
    FILE *output;
    int symbol;
    int letter;
    int count = 0;

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input output symbol\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((finp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s for input\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((output = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s for output\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    symbol = argv[3][0];

    while ((letter = fgetc(finp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (letter == symbol)
            count++;
    }

    fprintf(output, "The character being written was '%c' and it occurred %d times\n",
            symbol, count);

    fclose(finp);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample build and run

This assumes a suitable `makefile` exists to give you the compilation flags shown.  It's a subset of the flags I actually use, but the extra flags don't yield any extra warnings (errors) on this code.

```
$ make lc
    gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror lc.c -o lc 
$ cat input.txt
Hello my name is programmer!!
$ ./lc input.txt output.txt !
$ cat output.txt
The character being written was '!' and it occurred 2 times
$ ./lc input.txt output.txt e
$ cat output.txt
The character being written was 'e' and it occurred 3 times
$ ./lc input.txt output.txt m
$ cat output.txt
The character being written was 'm' and it occurred 4 times
$ ./lc input.txt output.txt Z
$ cat output.txt
The character being written was 'Z' and it occurred 0 times
$
```

Note how inconvenient this program design is.  Each time you run the program, you have to run `cat output.txt` or something similar to see what was produced.  There's a reason why programs write to standard output in preference to files, and this illustrates why.  Yes, I could use:

```
$ ./lc input.txt /dev/stdout o
The character being written was 'o' and it occurred 2 times
$
```

but it would be more convenient not to need to do so.

Since the symbol to be counted is pretty much mandatory, it should be the first argument.  The second argument should be optional but could specify the input file; if it is not supplied, the program would read standard input.  The third argument could also be optional, specifying the output file, defaulting to standard output:

```
Usage: lc symbol [input [output]]
```

Alternatively, and probably both more usefully and more conventionally, it should always write to standard output, and should read all the files on the command line after the mandatory symbol argument:

```
Usage: lc symbol [file ...]
```

If you want the output to go to a file, use I/O redirection.  Or allow the output to be specified via an option and argument:

```
Usage: lc [-o output] symbol [file ...]
```

or:

```
Usage: lc [-o output] -c symbol [file ...]
```

There's a cogent argument for suggesting that a mandatory argument should not need the `-c` prefix.  On the other hand, you could generalize the code so that if the `-c symbol` was not specified, it would do a count of all the symbols in the file, and generalize the printing so it printed out all the characters with a non-zero count, or even all the counts regardless.  You might also allow `-c symbol` to repeat, or track all the characters in the string after the `-c`.  There are many ways to vary this program usefully.